# (Symfony 4 form types) How do you make an entire subform required/not required based on a <select> value on the form?

Tags: javascript, forms, symfony, select, subform

Here is my form type class.  So the `< select>` field I am talking about is the 'numSubscriptionTiers':

```
class UserProfileType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('numSubscriptionTiers', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    '1' => 1,
                    '2' => 2,
                    '3' => 3
                ]
            ])
            ->add('subscriptionTier1', UserSubscriptionTierType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'entry_type' => UserSubscriptionTierType::class
            ])
            ->add('subscriptionTier2', UserSubscriptionTierType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'entry_type' => UserSubscriptionTierType::class
            ])
            ->add('subscriptionTier3', UserSubscriptionTierType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'entry_type' => UserSubscriptionTierType::class
            ])
```

If the user selects 1, then only make the subscriptionTier1 subform required, if the user selects 2, then only make the subscriptionTier1 and subscriptionTier2 subforms required, and so on...

I know there are form events like PRE_SET_DATA, POST_SUBMIT, etc... but can you add something similar to a JavaScript event from within the form type class?  Like some kind of onChange event to the numSubscriptionTiers select, and set the corresponding subforms' required attribute to true/false?

I have already gone here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#how-to-dynamically-generate-forms-based-on-user-data and it only gives an example of how to dynamically populate a choice list, not add a change event after it's options are specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `PRE_SUBMIT` event to [modify the form dynamically](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) to set the backend validation on your form elements.

Eg, if the sent value of the `numSubscriptionTiers` is `2`, then remove children `subscriptionTier1` and `subscriptionTier2` and add them again, but this time with additional `NotBlank` constraint:

```
// add imports

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // skipped for brevity
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, [$this, 'conditional']);
}

public function conditional(FormEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $data = $event->getData();

    // make sure tierCount is between 1-3
    $tierCount = min(3, max(1, (int) $data['numSubscriptionTiers'] ?? 0));

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $tierCount; $i++) {
        $childName = sprintf('subscriptionTier%d', $i);

        $form
            ->remove($childName)
            ->add($childName, UserSubscriptionTierType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'entry_type' => UserSubscriptionTierType::class,
                'constraints' => new NotBlank(),
            ]);
    }
}
```

I'm afraid the `HTML5 required` attribute has to be added dynamically using JavaScript, because PHP won't handle that on the client side. Well you could modify the `required` property of the dynamically readded field `subscriptionTier1`, but think what would happen if the user would change the `numSubscriptionTiers` to `2`. It would be impossible to submit the form, because of the `required` property on the `subscriptionTier1` element. Thus only JavaScript is a solution to that.

Comment: Hi Emix, if the user changes numSubscriptionTiers to 2, couldn't you just loop from 1 to 2, and remove/add subscriptionTier1 and subscriptionTier2 setting them required?  That is what I would want.

Comment: You can loop of course. I don’t have the knowledge what’s the logic between that form elements.

Comment: Hi Emix, you are only supposed to make required the forms going up the number selected in the select element.  So if the number is 2, then you make subscriptionTier1 and subscriptionTier2 required.

Comment: I've modified my answer.